# В mpdf выводится не весь код

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Всем привет.

Буду благодарен, если поможете разобраться, т.к. искал сам ответ в интернете, но решить так и не смог.

Есть HTML-код, который формируется и затем передается библиотеке mpdf для формирования файла.
Всё работает, но код выводится не до конца. Т.е. я передаю функции $mpdf->WriteHTML переменную с кодом, но выводится только его часть, вывод просто обрезается.

Если вместо $mpdf->WriteHTML я просто вывожу переменную через echo - есть весь нужный код.

Что пробовал:

1. Увеличивать лимиты pcre.backtrack_limit и pcre.recursion_limit - всё вроде бы увеличивается (видно через phpinfo()), о не помогает.
2. Также пробовал увеличивать лимит памяти и времени выполнения скриптов.
3. Пробовал, как советуют в документации $mpdf разбить код на меньшие блоки и выводить их в файл поочередно. Но, если я вызываю функцию $mpdf->WriteHTML несколько раз - в файл выводится только самый первый вызов и всё.

Comment: Думаю проблема в тегах. Данная библиотека не все теги поддерживает. Посмотрите в документации

Comment: На всякий случай проверил документацию - все теги поддерживаются. Да и не думаю, что как-то с этим связано: и тот код, который выодится в файл, и тот, который не выводится, состоят из одинаковых тегов (заголовоки + небольшие таблицы)

Comment: А сам этот кусок отдельно вывести получается?

Comment: Да, если вывести его отдельно. Т.е. полное ощущение, что код просто обрезается по количеству символов.